# one to many setter without object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I would like to be able to set a foreign key just by its id.

Sometimes, for some long scripts, the fact that I need to give the full foreign object to my setter method force me to do some database queries, wasting resources.

```
$entity = new SomeEntity();
$entity->setIdAnswer(42);

$em->persist($entity);
```

Instead of

```
$world = $em->getRepositorye('My/Bundle:Answer')->findOneById(42); 

$entity = new SomeEntity();
$entity->setIdAnswer( $world );

$em->persist( $entity);
```

How is it possible to occasionally set the foreign key with its integer key?

It would be great if we can do that without using some dirty code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you can achieve exactly that with reference proxies:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies

```
// $em instanceof EntityManager, $cart instanceof MyProject\Model\Cart
// $itemId comes from somewhere, probably a request parameter
$item = $em->getReference('MyProject\Model\Item', $itemId);
$cart->addItem($item);
```

Comment: it works great and it's very simple! (is it really doctrine2? :) )